# git checkout revision of a file in git gui

Tags: git, git-gui

Is there a good way to checkout revisions of a specific file in git gui like an add tool or something?

Tried adding a new tool as:

```
git checkout $REVISION $FILENAME
```

But it only allows branch revisions out, not a specific commit. Is there a particular var I coud use to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
 $ git show $REVISION:$FILENAME
```

with a ':' syntax as described in [`git rev-parse`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html).
That would be if you can specify for `$FILENAME` the **full** path relative to the top directory of your project (the directory including the `.git` directory).

This should be equivalent to:

```
 $ git checkout $REVISION -- $FILENAME
```