# GIT I want to cancel my checkout and get not committed changes back ! (Can I do that ?)

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have done commit. Next I made some changes to a file. Then I run the command checkout for only one file. Which looks like this:

```
git checkout HEAD^ filename.php
```

That did not help me at all. So I would like to cancel my checkout.
THE QUESTION IS:
Can I go back to not only last committed but also to changes made after (not committed)?

Comment: So you want to go back to `HEAD` for `filename.php`?

Comment: actually I am there right now :) but I made some changes after this state without committing them

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to what you want to do. Do you want to keep your current (uncommitted) changes, or do you want to discard them?

Comment: I think that I have already discarded them by using checkout. Now I am wondering can I cancel/reverse this "checkout" command in any way.

Comment: So you want to get your changes back?

Comment: yes :) I want them back but not only the one from last commit but also  those made after commit (but not committed!) Is that possible ?

Comment: I'm afraid not - when you do a checkout of a specific file or path, uncommitted changes are overwritten. Sorry!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2689265/6309

Answer (score 1):

The modern command (since Git 2.23, Q3 2019) would be [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore):

```
git restore -- filename.php
```

It would restore the file content from, by default, HEAD.

But it would also overwrite the original content (local uncommitted changes), leaving you with alternatives like a [VSCode timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71501328/6309) to get your local modification back.

A `git restore -p or -m` would at least attempt to merge hunks of code between the restore source and the restore location, instead of blindly overwriting everything.