# How to get all the discarded files from git which were not added or committed in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I had two branches and I was working on the second branch.
I unfortunately discarded all the files without committing or adding it to branch.
There were many files that I discarded and now I am unable to undo it.
Is there any way i could get all those files back.

i tried below commands to recover these files:

```
  `git reset --hard refs/original/refs/heads/master 
   git reset --hard`
```

I am also searching some commands that would bring back my files. Can you guys suggest me some solution for this.
Please help:(

Comment: Were these files ever commited at some point? If yes they're not lost.

Comment: no they were not committed anywhere

Comment: I was working in visual studio. is there something like caching or history

Comment: Sadly, no, not out-of-the-box. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446901/how-to-see-local-history-changes-in-visual-studio-code).

Comment: Files are not showing:(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover from git reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)