# How to see the last change made in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My app was working fine but it just stopped showing a page all of a sudden. I didn't change anything in the code but I think I "saved" an unsaved editor. Now I have no idea what file and change it was. Is there any way I can see what was the last change I made to to my project in VS code?

Can't use `git diff` or something because my last commit was a really long time ago.

Comment: Have you committed the changes after this event `"saved" an unsaved editor`? If not `git status` will tell you what you might have modified

Comment: Last time I committed was a long time ago so git status gives me a lot of changes in each file @SaurabhPBhandari

Comment: Probably checking the last modification time of the files might help, assuming that you didn't modify any code after your app stopped working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I see local history changes in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446901/how-can-i-see-local-history-changes-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called

> Git History

it will help you View *git log, file history, compare branches or commits*