# VSCode Timeline vs. JetBrains products Local History?

Tags: visual-studio-code, timeline

VSCode has introduced the Timeline feature in newer versions. I was expecting this Timeline like the Local History in JetBrains products but it's not like that, I have something like this:

[image: vscode Timeline view]

If I select `Include: Git History`, I can see Git Commits History in Timeline but I am unable to see file changes Local History like JetBrains Products. Am I missing something? Because this Timeline seems just only a Git Commits timeline. There's a plugin [Local History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history) for VSCode but I don't want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems only the Git history is currently available in the Timeline view without installing an extension. This is mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_timeline-view):

> Additional timeline sources can be contributed by extensions (although
> the API is still in the proposed stage), which will be shown in the
> unified Timeline view.

Answer (score -1):

Also with `Local File History` being worked on (it is in the Insiders v1.66 now), when enabled there will be a copy of the file saved which can be restored later.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71501328/836330 and [Local History: v1.66 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_66.md#local-history) for more.

`Workbench > Local History: Enabled`

> Controls whether the local file history is enabled.  WHen enabled, the
> file contents of an editor that is saved will be stored to a backup
> location and can be restored or reviewed later.  Changing this setting
> has no effect on existing file history entries.

[image: Local History view filter option]

Clicking on any of the `File Saved` entries opens a diff of that save and the current file.