# How to restore/recover files that were never pushed to the GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

While learning Git, I used the command `git init` for my entire student coding folder instead of just the practice `GIT/` folder.
But I didn't add, commit, or push them to the GitHub repository.

I made some other mistakes in the `GIT/` folder and I decided to delete the Git repositories I created on GitHub to "start from scratch".

In doing so, I also deleted all of code from my folders on VSCode.

I restored the repositories on GitHub, however this did not bring my other files back to VSCode.

The attached picture shows what I currently see in the VSCODE.
Any suggestions? I'd really appreciate it.

[image: VSCode screenshot]

Comment: if you did not commit the changes, they cannot be restored

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could they be on my icloud backup?

Comment: we have no way of knowing that

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: a good idea if you are experimenting, make a zip-backup BEFORE the experiment, put it on a flash drive and remove it from the usb port (in the proper manner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to install at least the [Local History VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history), as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57151798/6309).

That way, even if you do a destructive operation, you can still see old file "local history" (as recorded by VSCode, not Git), and restore your content.

If not, since you are talking about iCloud, double-check your [Time Machine status](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/time-machine-restore-3449071/), in case you could restore them from a backup.