# By mistake deleted an existing file before commit in git?

Tags: git

I was working on a file then deleted it by mistake before commiting. I restored it but I don't see any changes, was restored to the initial version. Is there a way to see what I was working on?

Comment: Via GIT - no. You can do it via IDE maybe. Jetbtains tools support Local History feature.
Also check your basket )

Comment: @IlyaMokin what about git fsck? Maybe it can help?

Comment: Was your file commited in previous commit?

Comment: @ToughCookie `git fsck` only operates on objects in its own database, not files in the working directory.

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmadKhan yes, it was, not a new file

Comment: @ToughCookie with `git fsck` we can restore `commits` which were fully lost from history, have no parent commits and even deleted from `reflog`. But unfortunately, we can not restore changes which were not committed at all

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your IDE. If you are using Jetbrains look for Local History in the File menu and see if it has stored those changes.

Edit - To avoid this in future consider using one of the two following plugins:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=micnil.vscode-checkpoints

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history

Be aware that this can cause VS Code to get confused, please see the following answer for more details:
[How to see local history changes in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446901/how-to-see-local-history-changes-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I'm using VS Code

Comment: Right click on the project item or folder and click Local History to display the history I believe

Comment: Don't see it. Should I have an extension for it?

Answer (score 0):

**I deleted a file but didn’t commit**

```
$ git checkout HEAD "filename"
```

**I deleted a file and committed the deletion**

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

**I committed the deletion and then I did more commits**

```
$ git log -- <filename>
$ git checkout <commit hash> -- <filename>
$ git checkout <deletion commit hash>~1 -- <filename>
```

**I deleted a file, committed and pushed**

```
$ git revert --no-commit <commit>
```

Here is the [reference](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/restoring-deleted-files/).

Comment: I deleted a file but didn’t commit $ git checkout HEAD "filename" I need to restore non commited changes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes