# How to find in VS Code a block of code saved but uncommitted?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to find in VS Code a block of code saved but uncommitted? Git log and file/line history are not helpful. Thank you.

Comment: It should be reflected in the source control change.. but is that something which you kept on gitignore ?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + G !? ("Source Control" activity), there you can see un-/&staged changes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71501328/836330 for file history, that may help.