# Recover deleted files from local git repo?

Tags: bash, git, rm, git-reset

I accidentally `rm`'d some files in a git repo.  Those files had been changed a lot and hadn't been `git add`'d yet.

Is there a way to restore the files to their 'last saved' state?

UPDATE

Just wanted to thank everyone for your responses, it wasn't a huge deal, I just deleted all my dotfiles :`(

Comment: If you never added nor committed them, then there is no last saved state.

Comment: I don't think so... You can recover the files but without changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `git`.

`git` can bring your files back with their **last commit state** rather than **last saved** state.

If you use vim, maybe some `*~` backup files are still in your git repo, then you can rename it.

If not, try some recovery tools like `TestDisk`.

BTW: `rm` is a dangerous command, try to add `-i` option with it: `rm -i xx`.

Answer (score 0):

Check first your IDE features.

- [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) has a "local history"
- VSCode now has a "[local timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71501328/6309)"

You might be able to restore your changed files that way.

Answer (score 0):

As [@tkausl says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72299377/recover-deleted-files-from-local-git-repo#comment127730125_72299377) you can recover `git add`ed files that aren't in a commit yet with a little more effort and awareness of how git stores added content, but `git add` is how you tell Git about new content, lots of times I'll `git add -p` to add stuff I've smoketested and continue with stuff I'm still beating on.

So, no,not unless your editor's got undo history going back that far.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted multiple files locally and did not commit the changes, go to your local repository path, open the git shell and type.

```
$ git checkout HEAD .
```

All the deleted files before the last commit will be recovered.

Adding "." will recover all the deleted the files in the current repository, to their respective paths.

For more details checkout the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).