# git reset --hard HEAD~1

Tags: git, git-reset

Is there any chance of recovering files that were not committed before this command? I used this command instead of --soft.... I am working on Linux/Visual Studio code

```
035e859 HEAD@{23}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
3704540 HEAD@{24}: commit: [TA-4] Creating a form onf Frontend that allows you to add TodoList
035e859 HEAD@{25}: commit: [TA-4] Creating a Controller that supports adding TodoList
5b1623d HEAD@{26}: commit: [TA-4] Project Configuration
c77dcb0 HEAD@{27}: commit: [TA-4] Adding Api Platform To the Project
```

I tried using the `git reset --hard HEAD@{23}` command, but unfortunately, I didn't get back the files that weren't committed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-reset%5D+recover+uncommitted , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-reset%5D+undo+uncommitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you never committed the files you're trying to get back, no git command will be able to recover them. Unless you have some other form of backup, I fear you're out of luck. Visual Studio Code's [local history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46446901/2422776) **may** be able to help you, but I'm not familiar with it enough to suggest anything concrete.