# How to undo git checkout on a file?

Tags: git

I was trying to push my changes to my git repository so i run a common command to add my files to stage.

```
git add --all
```

But from those files, i pretended to exclude a particular file and i ran by mistake:

```
git checkout <file>
```

instead of

```
git reset <file>
```

As result, my file changes were revert to it's last state. 
I lost all my recent changes....

How can i revert this mess?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can git undo a checkout of unstaged files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689265/can-git-undo-a-checkout-of-unstaged-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you can only revert changes if they were already in git version control. Unstaged changes aren't tracked by Git. It sucks, and is pretty annoying, and we've all done it.