# Undoing a git checkout -- <file>

Tags: git, undo, git-checkout

I didn't realize that I had uncommitted changes and I ran `git checkout -- 'file'`, is there a way to undo this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689265/can-git-undo-a-checkout-of-unstaged-files

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, git doesn't do any tracking of things that haven't yet been staged.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the file was staged prior, there is simply no way to get it back.  Git can only keep track of things that it is made aware of; any changes that it isn't made aware of can't be recovered by it alone.