# undo git soft reset or git checkout?

Tags: git

I added changes and made a commit locally

```
git add .
git commit -m "my changes..."
```

Realised I had made a mistake in my code so undid the commit

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Then I entered this

```
git checkout HEAD .
```

instead of this

```
git reset HEAD .
```

So I've dropped a clanger and lost my changes :(

Is there any way to get back the code? Undo the checkout? or is it still in the commit somewhere?

UPDATE: Think I might have an answer!

Found this - [Can git undo a checkout of unstaged files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689265/can-git-undo-a-checkout-of-unstaged-files)

Buried in one of the answers was "git reflog" - which I have never heard of.

Then found this - [Undoing git reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510276/undoing-git-reset).

So currently making a copy of my folder before doing anything else...