# How to show full-file Git blame in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

At one point I found a way to show line-by-line Git blame within Visual Studio Code. I now cannot recall or find the means with which to do that. I have the Git Blame extension, but that only shows blame on a single selected line.

Answer (score 261):

Use the [Gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension. It supports various options. Once installed, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to show the full file blame information.

Comment: So they implemented a ton of functionality but not git blame natively?

Comment: Or Ctrl+Shift+G B, if ones gitlens keymap is configured as 'chorded'.

Comment: At least on macOS there is a "Show File Annotation" icon in the top right corner. That toggles a bar showing the blame for each line.

Comment: Where do you see "Show File Annotation"? I can't find it. Do you use a plugin for this?

Comment: Once GitLens is installed, it also puts a little circular GitLens icon on the right of the tab bar (icon matches that for the extension in the left-hand activity bar).  Clicking that will also show/hide the file blame area.

Comment: "Show File Annotation" is definitely not here on macOS VSCode 1.50.1. The devs of VSCode itself didn't want people tracking them down from its source code and blaming them for issues like this, so they conveniently 'forgot' to include it :-P .

Comment: does anybody know hot to change the annotations panel's width? It takes 2/3 of widths in my case which is not nice

Comment: Not sure if it has always been like this, but the full name is "_GitLens — Git supercharged_".  Not to be confused with "_GitLens (Insiders)_"

Comment: LOL, this overbloated GitLens extension cannot basically show annotations with authors. They can't be serious! Hey, go and checkout WebStorm/IDEA to see how it should be done.

Comment: Where do I have to press `Alt+B`? In the file? Does not open or show anything.

Comment: The GitLens' annotations panel is absolutely disgusting. Looks horrible, takes 2/3 of the screen, doesn't show user names, lacks color codes indicating when changes were done. Webstorm/Intellij do it sooooo much better.

Comment: I really tried to like GitLens. It's just bloated, and takes a lot of previous screen space. Sure, it can do a lot, but you cannot do anything else with the editor. Combined with the fact that vscode cannot be split on two monitors, it's just not efficient to use.

Answer (score 44):

If you use the [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) plugin, you can also use the "File Annotations" icon in the top right of Visual Studio Code:

[image: GitLens - File Annotations Menu]

Or use the "GitLens: Toggle File Blame" command.

Comment: that's the correct answer

Comment: I have git lens but this symbol is nowhere to be found.

Comment: @Black you might not be in a git repo. i just tried: (1) new project: no icon. (2) `git init`: no icon. (3) git add and commit: no icon. (4) close and re-open that file: now the icon shows up as on the screenshot. (i am on the currently latest `v13.6.0`)

Answer (score 33):

On Mac, if you have the [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) plugin, it's <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: this will only works with GitLens Plugin, which you don't mention...

Comment: To install GitLens, type `Command + Shift + X`, search "GitLens", click "install"

Comment: Thank you. For anyone else who infrequently uses VS code like myself who was struggling to remember how to access the Command Palette pictured above, it's `Command + Shift + P`

Comment: I have GitLens installed and `Command` `Option` `G` `B` does nothing.

Answer (score 26):

You can view the commit history for an individual file without a plugin using the Timeline view.

[image]

See *[How can I view the Git history in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899765/how-can-i-view-the-git-history-in-visual-studio-code/60013101#60013101)* for more information.

Comment: But you can't view what commit a particular line was a part of directly

Comment: @Ridhuvarshan yup, that is correct, but I didn't want to install another VSCode plugin and this was "good enough" for my case

Comment: The question asks for a "git blame" equivalent: "show line-by-line git blame within vscode". You are giving a "git log" equivalent.

Comment: If you click the item, it shows the `diff` on the commit.... which was good enough for my use case (also didn't want to install another extension; I've used gitlens in the past but it was too heavy for me)

Answer (score 22):

I just installed Git Blame. It's out a while now, but it seems to be lightweight and very easy to use. I was able to get line-by-line details of who and when.

[image]

Comment: This looks much better, and simpler. GitLens is completely overbloated.

Comment: Can you share how you got this to show like key combinations or whatever else it took?

Comment: This one also shows blame info for every line that you ever move your cursor to, similar to GitLens. It doesn't offer a way to view git blame info a single time on demand like IntelliJ.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed this extension and set `gitblame.inlineMessageEnabled` to `true` in my settings json file. It worked as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 18):

Add the `Annotator` extension. [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.annotator) is the marketplace link to add it.

Source code: https://github.com/ryu1kn/vscode-annotator

[image]

Comment: possible usage: `ctrl + shift + p`, type `annotator` (or less), choose "Annotator: Annotate the current file or ...". Unfortunately (Annotator 1.0.0, VS Code 1.53.2), the annotated view is opened separately, with no syntax highlighting, block folding, scrolled to the top of the file and `ctrl + g` not working to go to the line

Comment: This deserves a bit more attention. Great tool and not bloated like GitLens.

Answer (score 4):

GitLens provides the functionality of full-file git blame. To execute the command:
Press Ctrl+Shift+G, followed by pressing only B.

**Note: When pressing B, do not press the Ctrl and Shift buttons. The command will work correctly in this manner.**

I have personally validated this command on VS Code version 1.81.0 and GitLens version 14.2.0. Some users have reported issues with this command, but it's possible they are inadvertently pressing Ctrl and Shift buttons while pressing B.

Comment: Thanks the tip to not press ctrl+shift when pressing B solved it for me

Comment: Still running in version 1.87.2 in 2024.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the way [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) integrates into Visual Studio Code. After looking around and trying a number of other git-related extensions, I settled on [*Git History*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory). It can be installed via VSCode Quick Open (typically, Ctrl+P) with `ext install donjayamanne.githistory`.

It provides both full file and line-specific git blame from the context menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into the user/workspace's *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)* file:

```
"gitlens.currentLine.enabled": false
```

Comment: Does that affect the Git blame thingy? How have all the previous answers with GitLens missed it? Is it something that changed in a newer version? What system and version was it tested on? Version of GitLens and Visual Studio Code. Operating system.