# visual studio code built-in story for reviewing git commit history and doing diffs of its contents

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-history-graph

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899765/how-can-i-view-the-git-history-in-visual-studio-code/60013101?noredirect=1#comment112407427_60013101) SO question details are provided on use of out of box vscode "[Timeline view](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_timeline-view)" experience is covered as a way to look at commit history and diffs from a file scope perspective.

Does out of box vscode support exist for gui review of a commit history, i.e. `git log`, and then diff'ng the contents of it, i.e. `git show <commit id>`, from a commit scope not Timeline file by file scope or extension marketplace offering such as [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens), [Git History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory) or [Git Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph)?