# Why does the 'git blame' timeline sometimes appear in vscode, and how do I hide it?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I use vscode. Sometimes I seem to click or type something accidentally and a timeline view (similar to the one described in [How can I view the Git history in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899765/how-can-i-view-the-git-history-in-visual-studio-code)) appears.

[image]

**How do I close the timeline view?**

I thought the option to hide the timeline would be in **View > Appearance** but I can't see any references to 'timeline' history' 'commits' etc.

Right now I just close the file and reopen it but I'm sure there's a proper solution.

Comment: This looks like a `git blame`, you might find an option under this name.

Comment: @tkausl indeed it does. Sadly I can't see anything like 'show/hide git blame' either.

Comment: look in the `gitlens` options: command `GitLens: Toggle File Blame Annotations`

Comment: That's it @rioV8 - specifically it's called just `GitLems: Toggle File Blame`. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I also unintentionally opened blame history and didn't know how.

**The reason why the timeline is opening unexpectedly** is that clicking the message above the first line in a file opens and close the latest blame - see red area in the screenshot.

[image]

To fix it (thanks [GitKraken for the advice on Twitter](https://twitter.com/GitKraken/status/1667180703891574785)):

`Command/ctrl + shift + P` > `GitLens: Open Settings` > then scroll down to `Git CodeLens`:

[image]

Comment: I'm marking this as the preferred answer as it answers the question about why the git blame history appeared in the first place.

Comment: This is sooooo anti-intuitive!

Comment: Don't know why the sidebar doesn't have a very obvious "HIDE" button!

Comment: thanks man i got stuck on this

Comment: You can hide it again by clicking the same text that opens it.

Comment: Thank you! This has been bugging me for years - I always have to google to figure it out. Happy that this is the first result.

Answer (score 21):

[image]

Click on the `Toggle file blame` on the right upper corner of the Visual Studio code (1.67)

Comment: As a note, it appears with a red icon when it's open which makes it more visible; but I had never noticed until I came to this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You probably hit the shortcut key for the command: `GitLens: Toggle File Blame Annotations`

Comment: I seem to do this with a stray mouse click... yet cannot undo this with a mouse click anywhere... anyone know?

Comment: Hit Ctrl+Shift+P, enter GitLens: Toggle File Blame, and click Enter.

Comment: @KCD Check stefancho's answer below.

Comment: You can undo it by hitting Esc

Comment: Thanks. I was getting irritated, you saved me. The UI seems to be designed without any thought. It opens in almost half the screen and doesn't have the option to resize, you can't right-click and close it.

Answer (score 1):

[version 1.52.1] Right-click 'TIMELINE', then click 'Hide'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you turn off those inline authorship messages that are easy to click, which pops out the annoying sidebar.

Ctrl+Shift+P => "Open Settings" => Ctrl+F for "Adds authorship CodeLens" Deselect the line.
[Turn off GetCodeLens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuIPN.png)