# How do i set the number of commits that are shown in the new showOutgoingChanges in the november insider release?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-history

I am trying to see all the previous commits i made to a repo. The new showIncomingChanges and showOutgoingChanges settings are supper useful in that regard. i can see what code i added/removed in previous commit. However this is super limited now because it only shows one commit.

Is it possible to increase the number of commits that are visible ? I imagine its tracking the commits that i did not push upstream yet. I actually want to browse history for commits that are already pushed as well.

Hope this makes sense.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't (as far as I'm aware).

And I think you may have misunderstood what this feature really is. I I understand it correctly, outgoing commits are commits that have not been pushed to the remote- based on what your local repository knows about the commit the remote branch is at the last time you fetched updates about that. It's not for surveying "previous commits". If you want to see information about previous commits, you should see Q&A like [How can I view the Git history in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37899765/11107541) or similar.