# How to recover changes that discard by git checkout -f

Tags: git, restore, git-checkout

My changes were gon after I run command `git checkout -f`

Is there a way to recover my changes?

I did not commit my changes and also it's unstaged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can git undo a checkout of unstaged files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689265/can-git-undo-a-checkout-of-unstaged-files)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-checkout%5D+uncommitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to recover your changes won't be git, since files were not committed.

However, you *could* recover them, provided you're using a sufficently advanced IDE with local changes save feature.

If not, the picture might be grim, but it's hopefully a lesson to remember : commit often, even on temporary branches when you're unsure.

---

**edit after comments :**

Good news, you're on PhpStorm. *(you seem to know how to proceed already, I'm just adding it for the record here)*

[image]

Let's note that most modern IDEs have similar functionality.

Comment: Also, consider using `git stash` when it's relevant.

Comment: @Obsidian I tend to use branches, but yes, stashing is also a good way to save changes you're unsure of but don't want to risk losing.

Comment: thanks, I was using phpstorm its already has the ability to view local changes