# recovery files from local git which not added and commited yet

Tags: git, gitlab

I did something a mistake to `git checkout .` thought the modified files were not added and committed yet, is it possible to get that file back ?

when I did git status all files were gone, not deleted but gone.

Does anyone ever have this problem? 
could I get that file back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689265/can-git-undo-a-checkout-of-unstaged-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can git undo a checkout of unstaged files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689265/can-git-undo-a-checkout-of-unstaged-files)

Comment: Unless you are developing in an IDE with history tracking you are SOL :(