# the following packages are broken because other packages they depend on are missing. these broken packages must be rebuilt before they can be used

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

The question title comes from an error returned by [the Haskell tool Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/) and it's followed by a line containing the following:

```
installed package <a> is broken due to missing package <b>
```

One can find reports of similar errors online. In my case the specific error is:

```
installed package haddock-library-1.5.0.1 is broken due to missing package haddock-library-1.5.0.1-919WkNWGnku6Kvc4vlhbv1-attoparsec
```

Returned during the installation of Pandoc. Here i am asking about the generic error, because i feel like it refers to something that i didn't learn reading the Stack documentation. Maybe it's obvious, or maybe if other people turn to have the same problem we could think about expanding the doc.

So, package `a` is broken because package `b` is missing. Missing from where? From the resolver? Is there anything i can do, or should i rather change the resolver? The broken packages must be rebuilt ... after i changed the resolver? If i want to understand the error better do i want to look on Stack, Cabal or GHC? Or do we want people to open issues on the tracker for package `a` when this error happens?

Comment: Do you happen to be on Arch or some related distribution? In `$HOME/.stack/config.yaml`, is there a line mentioning system packages? (if so, try removing it)

Comment: nope, my `~/.stack/config.yaml` is empty

Comment: What version of stack are you using ?

Comment: using version 1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has already been reported and resolved. The fix was included in `stack-1.9.1`.

- https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll/issues/659
- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4071
- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/pull/4111

Comment: with this question, i was trying to get into the understanding of the internal data model of some software, like i did successfully [in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21025314/393758). Stack overflow has changed though, so it seems like now it's not that popular to ask broader questions. Thanks for fixing this specific problem, you get the correct answer :)