# WWW and Github folder synchronization

Tags: github, wamp, github-for-windows

Still new to Github and was wondering if its possible to synchronize a WWW specific folder to Github project folder.

Let's say, I am working on **/www/my-project/** and I have github folder **/github/my-project-repo/**
The main question is, how can I easily move file from my-project to my-project-repo just similarly to committing. Copy-pasting seems like a dull method to do. Any tips helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure it out... Here are some video tutorial that helped me along the way:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=mYjZtU1-u9Y

- Basic fundamentals of Git
- The difference between Git and GitHub
- Installation and setup tutorial for Git
- Basic (but core) command lines of Git

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=8r_IErxmoUc

- Account signup tutorial for GitHub and general tips
- Using GitHub with Git (configuration and demo)
- Installation tutorial of GitHub Windows Client (GUI)
- Introduction to Branching, Merging, Cloning, and Forking

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=STJBFXskfCc

- Example of development cycle using Git and GitHub
- More details on Branching, Merging, Cloning, and Forking
- Introduction to Merging Conflicts

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCv2BIQpPgI&feature=player_detailpage

- In-depth look in Merging Conflicts
- Tagging
- Reverting Commits

Comment: So what was your sequence of (git) commands that allowed you to solve your issue?

Comment: the basic to say the least. All I did was the move storage directory to /www/. did a git cd /my-project/, git config, git init, etc. I stop tracking the repo that was save on Docs/Github/— my first storage directory. To say the least, I was really new to git and github so I have no idea what I am doing even at the start at the beginning of installation.

Comment: Sounds good enough. I have including your comment in my answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` option of the git command:

If you are modifying files in my_project, but want them taken into account in my-project-repo git repo, you can do:

```
git --work-tree=/www/my-project/ --git-dir= /github/my-project-repo/.git status
git --work-tree=/www/my-project/ --git-dir= /github/my-project-repo/.git add -A .
git --work-tree=/www/my-project/ --git-dir= /github/my-project-repo/.git commit -m "add files from my-project"
```

You might want to [refresh your working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107789/using-git-how-do-you-reset-the-working-tree-to-the-state-of-the-index) in `/github/my-project-repo` after modifying its index with your `git add`.

```
cd /github/my-project-repo
git checkout .
```

Beware though of concurrent modifications you could have on *common* files: that last checkout would erase and overwrite them by what you added from `/www/my-project`.

If you want to be sure to preserve any work in progress in `/github/my-project-repo`:

```
 git stash save --keep-index
 git stash drop
```

---

The OP found a simpler solution, and:

- moved the storage directory to `/www/`.
- `cd /my-project/`,
- `git config`, `git init`, etc.

> I stop tracking the repo that was save on `Docs/Github/` — my first storage directory.

Comment: how do I pass correct directory path? My current wamp directory is c:\wamp\www\my-project\ and my github directory c:\users\xxx\Documents\GitHub

Comment: @edden put your wamp directory as working tree in the `--work-tree` parameter, and `c:\users\xxx\Documents\GitHub\.git` in the `--git-dir` parameter. Those two parameters allow you to pass the correct directory paths.