# How to get a previous file from another branch

Tags: git

I am developing in the `feature/porting_to_ubuntu` branch.

I want to checkout the `tests/test_setting.xls` Excel binary file from  `feature/change_excel_format` branch.

How do I restore a previous file?

[image]

Comment: What GUI client are you using?

Comment: Very easy to find on Google. http://nicolasgallagher.com/git-checkout-specific-files-from-another-branch/ - Command line though. You didn't tell us what GUI you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get just one file from another branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 0):

The command is `git checkout feature/change_excel_format -- tests/test_setting.xls`