# Git pull and merge during a merge

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

With Git I have done a pull on the other developers branch, then I merged into my branch.  When I ran the app I realized the other developer forgot to check in a new resource, he promptly checked it in.  How do I grab that new file while I'm in the middle of a merge?

I don't want to lose all the work I did with the mergetool by undoing what I have so far.  I also don't want to check it in as I can't test it without the resource file and I don't want to check in broken code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

- fetch (which doesn't require that your working tree is clean, meaning your merge is still in progress)
- checkout the file from origin/otherBranch (as in "[How to get just one file from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364223/6309)")

  ```
  git checkout origin/otherBranch -- aFile
  ```

That would override '`aFile`' though, which means I assume your merge in progress doesn't involve that file, or the work o it would be lost.

As The [OP Ian Hern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313586/ian-hern) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24254443/6309), you also can checkout the branch after pulling the other branch.
Redoing a merge then can work.

Comment: I haven't tested this as I didn't want to wait so I just checked in a broken commit, will try it if it ever happens to me again (it probably will lol).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to checkout that other branch, do a pull, and then checkout my mid-merge branch again.  And then ran merge again and it added it in.

Comment: Ok, I have added your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.