# difference between origin/branch_name and branch_name?

Tags: git, bitbucket

for pushing to bitbucket.

If I do: `git push origin origin/branch_name` my commits are not pushed.

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

If I do `git push origin branch_name` my commits are pushed:

```
Counting objects: 160, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 2.10 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 20 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

so what is the origin/ mean in front of the branch_name? And why does it matter?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that there are different types of branches:

- (Purely) *local* branches, i.e. branches you commit to,
- *Branches that live in a remote repository*, for lack of a better term. You may know the remote repository in question under a remote name, such as `origin`. From that repository's point of view, though, such a branch is *local*. Welcome to Distributed Version Control! `:)`
- *Remote-tracking* branches. Also simply called *remote branches*, as in the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches), but I find this phrase confusing; *remote-tracking branch* is more accurate. They're special local branches whose sole purpose is to reflect the state of *branches that live in a remote repository* at the time of your last communication with the server. In particular, you can't commit to branches of this type.

Here, `branch_name` is a *local* branch, whereas `origin/branch_name` is a *remote-tracking* branch; it reflects the state of the corresponding *branch that lives in `origin`*.

Right after running

```
git fetch
```

the *remote-tracking* branch `origin/master` and the corresponding *branch that live in `origin`* should be perfectly in sync (modulo concurrent pushes to the remote server, of course). It shouldn't be a surprise, then, that

```
git push origin origin/branch_name
```

doesn't push anything: you're essentially attempting to push stuff that is already present in the ancestry of the corresponding *branch that live in `origin`* .

However, if your *local* branch, `branch_name`, is ahead by one or more commits,

[image]

then running

```
git push origin branch_name
```

will push the commits contained in `branch_name` to `origin/branch_name`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

using a graphical tree viewer (like `gitk --all`) will show you, that `origin/mybranch` and `mybranch` might differ.

`origin` is just the *default* name for a cloned *remote*, which (in your case) contains a branch `mybranch` (just like your local repository)

so when you ask to push `origin/mybranch` to `origin`, you are synchronizing the `origin` remote with itself, hence it doesn't do anything (luckily the *remote* is always in synch with itself).

the name `origin` is arbitrary, and could have been set with the `--origin` flag when cloning.

Answer (score 3):

- `origin/branch_name` is a branch on the remote machine
- just `branch_name` is a branch on the local machine

Comment: I disagree. `origin/branch_name` is on your local machine but tracks a branch on a remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

origin is whats stored remotely on github

without origin is what is stored locally on your computer

when you commit 1st you are commit locally to your computer

when you push origin branch name you are pushing to github

Comment: where does github come into this game? `git` allows for many remote servers and github is just one of them.

Comment: @umläute I think he used GitHub to reflect what the "remote" part means.

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder I know, but it makes me cry *so* hard, if people just conflate `github` with `git`. also the question was tagged `bitbucket` (for no apparent reason except that the OP probably used bitbucket as their remote)