# Where are my local remote branches?

Tags: git

I have just cloned a git repo that already have a bunch of remote branches. I have poked around in the .git folder but I cannot find them, when I do a `git show-ref` I get:

```
cf8e5e98c27ee83a1ff2122f2c2a214e8e06383d refs/heads/master
cf8e5e98c27ee83a1ff2122f2c2a214e8e06383d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
76541f13b20bb25056788f092f58547d4657bed8 refs/remotes/origin/example
cf8e5e98c27ee83a1ff2122f2c2a214e8e06383d refs/remotes/origin/master
cf8e5e98c27ee83a1ff2122f2c2a214e8e06383d refs/remotes/origin/smpl-remote
e34b3b7e54174c5b862ae16d29a3079c060c160e refs/remotes/origin/test
```

But the folder: `.git\refs\remotes\origin` only contains the `HEAD` file

If open the repo in eclipse I can see them:

[image]

What am I missing here?

I just tried to remove the internet connection (wifi and wired) but I can still list the remote branches, where in the .git folder is that information??

Comment: Why are you doing this the hard way?  What does `git branch -r` tell you?

Comment: That is not really the point. Does it require online access to list remote branches?

Comment: If by "online" you mean "connected to a network that allows access to that particular Git server", then yes.  They're branches that are on a remote server.

Comment: You don't need access to them to list the remote branches, you DO need access to update them with `git fetch`.

Comment: Ok I thought that when you cloned a repository you would get a local copy of each of the remote branches at the time you cloned the repo. The state of those branches would then be updated each time you do a git fetch

Comment: Check `.git\packed-refs`

Comment: @u123 You're correct. Makoto is incorrect. Only one local branch is checked out in a clone, but you get a copy of all the branches in that repo as *remote-tracking* branches; they're like local branches that you modify directly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125162/difference-between-origin-branch-name-and-branch-name/26125339#26125339

Comment: @u123 Why exactly do you care where Git stores those remote-tracking branches, though? As a user that's none of your concern...

Answer (score 4):

[Andrew C answered in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570988/where-are-my-local-remote-branches#comment45452240_28570988), but I'll add a bit more.

The "missing" branches are "packed".  This saves space (and sometimes saves time although mostly that's a wash).

In fact, all branches get packed at various times (when `git pack-refs` runs, usually on behalf of `git gc`).  That's one of several reasons you are supposed to use various front-end and back-end commands (`git branch`, `git for-each-ref`, `git update-ref`, `git symbolic-ref`) to work with branches, rather than just peeking into `.git/refs/` directly.

It's sometimes convenient to add `.git/packed-refs` to your peeking, but remember that this part is an implementation detail and may change.