# error: pathspec 'test-branch' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, github, git-checkout, git-fork

I am a new user of Git. I have forked a repository called Spoon-Knife (available for practicing forking with Git). Then, I cloned it locally by running

```
git clone https://github.com/rohinichoudhary/Spoon-Knife.git
```

This repository contains three branches, i.e.

- `master`,
- `test-branch`,
- `change-the-title`.

When I run `git branch`, it only shows `*master`, not the remaining two branches. And when I run

```
git checkout test-branch
```

I get the following error:

> error: pathspec 'test-branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Why is this happening? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure your branch name is written correctly of same repository.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> When I run `git branch`, it only shows `*master`, not the remaining two branches.

`git branch` doesn't list `test_branch`, because no such local branch exist in your local repo, yet. When cloning a repo, only one local branch (`master`, here) is created and checked out in the resulting clone, irrespective of the number of branches that exist in the remote repo that you cloned from. At this stage, `test_branch` only exist in your repo as a [*remote-tracking* branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125162/difference-between-origin-branch-name-and-branch-name/26125339#26125339), not as a *local* branch.

> And when I run
>
> ```
> git checkout test-branch
> ```
>
> I get the following error [...]

You must be using an "old" version of Git. In more recent versions ([from v1.7.0-rc0 onwards](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70c9ac2f1999b7e0c17a864235537cffe29dfea4)),

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in
>   exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat [`git checkout <branch>`] as
>   equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

Simply run

```
git checkout -b test_branch --track origin/test_branch
```

instead. Or update to a more recent version of Git.

Comment: I am using `git version 1.9.1`

Comment: @rohinichaudhary are you sure you are using 1.9.1? It doens't/shouldn't behave like that https://gist.github.com/AD7six/7ee86b44804319979dff

Comment: @rohinichaudhary Run `git branch -r`. If you see `origin/test-branch` listed and if you're really using v1.9.1, then `git checkout test_branch` should work as explained in my answer.

Comment: @Jubobs when i tried your solution, again a error was encountered. then i again tried with `git checkout test-branch`. it worked.

Comment: I get `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'V1' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/V1' which can not be resolved as commit?` from that.

Comment: Your solution led me to the problem I was facing, with "open project" repository. On the manual I had, it said to clone the branch "stable" but when I went looking for it, it didn't exist on the repository, the actual version was "stable/6". That was why I was getting the "error: pathspec 'stable' did not match any file...". Maybe this can help someone else too!

Comment: git checkout -b test_branch worked for me. adding --track gave a fatal error.

Answer (score 68):

The modern Git should able to detect remote branches and create a local one on checkout.

However if you did [a shallow clone](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt) (e.g. with `--depth 1`), try the following commands to correct it:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
git fetch --all
```

and try to checkout out the branch again.

Alternatively try to unshallow your clone, e.g. `git fetch --unshallow` and try again.

<sup>See also: [How to fetch all remote branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39957760/55075)</sup>

Comment: None of the other answers worked for me (with Git 2.7.4) but this one did, thanks! I think I must have cloned this repository with --depth 1, and thus ended up with a weird setting of `remote.origin.fetch`.

Comment: Yes this answer worked for me and was much  straightforward compared to others. Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

My friend, you need to create those corresponding branches locally first, in order to check-out to those other two branches, using this line of code

```
git branch test-branch
```

and

`git branch change-the-title`

then only you will be able to do **git checkout** to those branches

Also after creating each branch, take latest changes of those particular branches by using **git pull origin branch_name**   as shown in below code

```
git branch test-branch
git checkout test-branch
git pull origin test-branch
```

and for other branch named **change-the-title**  run following code =>

```
git branch change-the-title
git checkout change-the-title
git pull origin change-the-title
```

Happy programming :)

Comment: your answer can be another approach. But direct checkout to remote branch also works (as suggested in above answer), if you have clone full repository, not a particular branch.

Comment: @rohinichaudhary : absolutely correct. In older version of Git, it didn't worked for me. I were using an older version of Git, now going to update :)

Answer (score 17):

You can also get this error with any version of git if the remote branch was created after your last clone/fetch and your local repo doesn't know about it yet.  I solved it by doing a `git fetch` first which "tells" your local repo about all the remote branches.

```
git fetch
git checkout test-branch
```

Comment: Simple & easy explanation about `git fetch`. +1

Answer (score 10):

just follow three steps, git branch problem will be solved.

`git remote update`
`git fetch`
`git checkout --track origin/test-branch`

Comment: Works for me as well. I might add that if you have old changes preventing you to switch branch, you can discard them with "git reset --hard"

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

To fix it you need to fetch first

```
$ git fetch origin

$ git rebase origin/master
```

Current branch master is up to date.

```
$ git checkout develop
```

Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from origin.

Switched to a new branch ‘develop’

Answer (score 0):

This error can also appear if your git branch is not correct even though case sensitive wise.
In my case I was getting this error as actual branch name was "CORE-something" but I was taking pull like "core-something".

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because the instruction on the Web was

`git checkout https://github.com/veripool/verilog-mode`

which I did in a directory where (on my own initiative) i had run `git init`.
The correct Web instruction (for newbies like me) should have been

`git clone https://github.com/veripool/verilog-mode`

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me

```
git pull
```

Then checkout the required branch

Answer (score 0):

git fetch && git checkout branch-name

Comment: Hi priyanka, please consider the elaboration for your answers as they do appears more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check first if any file is modified in you current branch using

**git status**

if any add or remove it then try

**git checkout branchName**

Answer (score 0):

If it is a tag, you can do `git fetch --all --tags` and then `git checkout <TAG_NAME>`

Answer (score -2):

Try cloning before doing the checkout.

do git clone "where to find it" then after cloning check out the branch

Comment: The poster clearly showed the git clone command used as well as the command to attempt to checkout the branch.