# git: why do I get the error error: pathspec '<branch name>' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, version-control

I've found an interesting scenario. This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800454/error-pathspec-test-branch-did-not-match-any-files-known-to-git).

I have git (version 1.8.3.1) and I created a branch locally, then I pushed it to my remote repository. I checked (`git branch -a`) that it exists on the remote repository.

Now, I have the repository setup on another machine. When I run the following commands (using the version 1.8.3.1):

```
git fetch
git checkout <my branch>
```

I checkout to my branch correctly.

However, I also have the git version git version 2.6.3. And when I run the above commands, I get the error:

```
error: pathspec '<branch name>' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I'd expect this error in case of an older git version (see the linked question), but why does it fail for the version 2.6.3?

If I checkout to my branch using the older version of git, I can also checkout it using the git version 2.6.3.

Does it mean that git developers decided to remove this nice functionality introduced in v1.7.0-rc0 and I have to run `git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>` or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Try `git fetch origin <branch>:refs/remotes/origin/<branch> && git checkout <branch>`. Your `git fetch` doesn't get anything. Besides, you need to make sure that `origin` exists. If it does not, run `git remote add origin <url>` first. `origin` can be another name and replace `orign` in `refs/remotes/origin/<branch>` with the other name if it has already been there.

Comment: Add the output of `git branch -r` to your question. I think I know the answer, but will need to refer to it.

Comment: You can use `git branch -a` to check if the branch name is exist on remote. If exists, then **copy** (not input) the branch name after `git checkout`. Such as if the branch name is `–a`, there usually cause typos since `–a` is different from `-a`. So you'd better copy the branch name.

Comment: Has the problem been solved?

Answer (score 2):

If `origin/mybranch` does exist, a simple

```
git checkout mybranch
```

should be enough.

So double check what `git branch -r` shows you after a `git fetch`.

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to

```
$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```