# How to solve "git checkout branch" did not match any file(s) known to git?

Tags: git

There is a repository on bitbucket and I have a branch.

When I write: `git branch -a`, I get only my current branch and it doesn't list other branches.

When I write `git checkout branch_name`, I get: `error: pathspec 'branch_name' did not match any file(s) known to git`.

`git remote show origin`:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh:URL
  Push  URL: ssh:URL
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    branch_name tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    branch_name merges with remote branch_name
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    branch_name pushes to branch_name (up to date)
```

`git branch --all -vv`

```
* branch_name                {an id} [origin/branch_name] A commit
  remotes/origin/branch_name {an id} A commit
```

Comment: What does `git remote -vv` show? Does it show the URL to your bitbucket repository? Did you clone from that repository or did you initialize an empty repository locally?

Comment: Yess, it shows the URL.
I cloned it.

Comment: Please provide in your question the actual output of `git branch --all -vv` and `git remote show origin`

Comment: try `git fetch` and then `git checkout`

Comment: @matt I provided it!

Comment: @ullaskunder already tried it and doesn't work

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800878/15107749

Comment: Yep, just as I thought, you've got a single-branch clone. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that when you cloned this repo, you made a *single-branch clone.* So the branch that you asked for is the only branch you can see.

(For "solutions", see [How do I "undo" a --single-branch clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714159/how-do-i-undo-a-single-branch-clone) .)