# Why does git log not show anything new after git fetch?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I am learning about working with Git remotes by reading the [relevant section of the Pro Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

If you clone a repository, the command automatically adds that remote repository under the name "origin". So, `git fetch origin` fetches any new work that has been pushed to that server since you cloned (or last fetched from) it.

It’s important to note that the `git fetch` command only *fetches* the data to your local repository; it doesn’t automatically merge it with any of your work or modify what you’re currently working on. You have to merge it manually into your work when you’re ready.

Here is what I tried. I cloned a repository and edited a file.
In the original repository, someone updated the same file and pushed.
Then,

1. I ran `git fetch`.
   It showed some update progress message. However, `git log` did not show that update. Did I misunderstand what `git fetch` does? Am I missing something?
2. I ran `git pull`, and I got

> error: Your local changes to 'hello_world.c' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Here, I believe it's also merging and to avoid accidental data loss, it aborts.

**Edit:**
Thanks for the answers. Actually before looking at the answers, I was trying myself and realized the same with the following commands / outputs:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
d0006a6bfa95e0e90aa820a0e50d31a548625652    HEAD
d0006a6bfa95e0e90aa820a0e50d31a548625652    refs/heads/master
$ git ls-remote .
14375458b8a6b84f82d9fa4d2ded0bb8c9e87431    HEAD
14375458b8a6b84f82d9fa4d2ded0bb8c9e87431    refs/heads/master
d0006a6bfa95e0e90aa820a0e50d31a548625652    refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
d0006a6bfa95e0e90aa820a0e50d31a548625652    refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Also with following commands:

```
$git log origin --oneline
$git log --oneline
```

Thank you for bearing with my stupid questions ;-)

Comment: *[...] git fetch command pulls the data to your local repository [...]* Careful with the term "pull"; it has a very specific meaning in Git, and using it the way you do can only lead to confusion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default, `git log` shows the log of the current branch. Since fetching without merging doesn't change anything in your current (local) branch, the `git log` output doesn't change.

`git log` can take the `--all` option to show the history of all branches, local and remote. Alternatively, you can explicitly list the remote branch as in `git log origin/master`.

Answer (score 7):

You wrote

> However, git log did not show that update. Did I misunderstand what git fetch does? Am I missing something?

You seem to be confused about what both `git log` and `git fetch` do.

Under the assumption that a branch called `master` is currently checked out—you may also be in detached-HEAD state, but let's keep things simple, for the sake of this explanation—the command `git log`, without any other arguments, is equivalent to `git log master`. This command tells Git

> Show me all the commits that are in the ancestry of the local `master` branch.

However, you need to understand that `git fetch origin` doesn't affect/update your local branches, such as `master`. Instead, new commits from `origin` (or any other remote you fetch from) are put in [*remote-tracking branches*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26125339/2541573).

Remote-tracking branches are *special* local branches whose sole purpose is to reflect the state of branches that live in a remote repository at the time of your last communication with the server. In particular, you can't commit to branches of this type.

What you probably want is to run

```
git fetch origin
```

to fetch all new commits from `origin` and puts them in remote-tracking branches (including `origin/master`, here), and then

```
git log master..origin/master
```

to show a log of all the "new" commits that were added on the remote `master` branch, i.e. the branch that lives on the remote server you know as `origin`, which your remote-tracking branch `origin/master` keeps track of.

Answer (score 4):

After `git fetch`, your local repo knows the changes from the remote repo but hasn’t applied them to your local branches yet.

`git log` without additional parameters shows the log of the current branch – and you haven’t merged the remote changes into that branch yet.

`git pull` does `git fetch` and `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

Your error message means that there are uncommitted changes in your local repo. You can commit or stash them (as the message states) and try `merge` (or `pull`) again.

Answer (score 1):

Your local branches never get updated from a fetch, only the tracking branches do, `git pull` on the other hand does,

`git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`

You can't see any updates in `git log` simply beause you are running it on the wrong branch, to see your changes from just a `git fetch` then you need to `git log` on the right branch, which in your case would be

```
git log origin/master
```