# Why can I still checkout a branch I deleted on remote GitLab

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I have a project on GitLab, from the master I created a branch called `Processing-points`, not from the command line but with the web interface.

Then I deleted the branch `Processing-points`, also from the web interface. So everything is ok from the web interface, but on my local computer, I can still checkout the deleted branch. How is that possible?

This is the suggestions I get when I ask to checkout:

```
ag@ag-Precision-7520:~/catkin_ws/3D_EM$ git checkout 
HEAD                                    origin/master                           origin/Processing-points-multi-thread 
master                                  origin/origin/parallelization           parallelization 
ORIG_HEAD                               origin/parallelization                  pcl_filters 
origin/HEAD                             origin/pcl_filters                      Processing-points-multi-thread
```

Comment: It appears you either did not delete the local branch, or you never deleted the tracking branch, and `git checkout` created a new local copy.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125162/difference-between-origin-branch-name-and-branch-name/26125339#26125339

Comment: Indeed, @Jubobs, the answer you link to explains the situation in a much better way that what I was about to write :-).

Comment: @MatthieuMoy Coming from you, this comment makes me very happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can troubleshot the issue with below aspects:

1. Use `git branch -r` to **check if the tracking branch `origin/Processing-points` exist or not**. If it exists, you can use below commands update:

   ```
   git fetch -p
   git checkout master #if the HEAD is on local Processing-points branch
   git branch -D Processing-points
   ```
2. If the tracking branch `origin/Processing-points` not exist, that's caused  **the `Processing-points` branch already checked out locally before deleting the branch remotely**. And Even you deleted the remote  `Processing-points` branch, the local branch  `Processing-points`always exist. And you can use `git branch -D Processing-points` to delete the local one.

Comment: I use git branch -r and saw origin/Processing-points and then i justa add to do git fetch -p to have this response :

Comment: Yes, you can execute `git fetch -p` to prune the deleted branch `Processing-points` from remote repo. But the local `Processing-points` branch still exists. If you also want to delete the local `Processing-points` branch, continue to execute `git branch -D Processing-points` to delete the local `Processing-points` branch.

Answer (score 3):

You can clean up outdated references to remote branches with:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `git branch -r` and saw origin/Processing-points in the list. I just had to do `git fetch -p` to have this response : `x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/Processing-points-multi-thread` and everything seems fine. 
Thanks for your help!