# How to get just one file from another branch, but which does not exist in the current branch?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have very a similar question to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364223/1716560

I have two branches: `uk` and `uk-prod`:

```
git checkout uk-prod
Already on 'uk-prod'

git diff --name-status uk-prod..uk
A       pages/Advanced Types.md
A       pages/Basic Types.md
A       pages/Classes.md
```

I want to get only file `pages/Advanced Types.md`:

```
git checkout uk -- "page/Advanced Types.md"
```

But git throw:

```
error: pathspec 'page/Advanced Types.md' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

As far as I understand, it happens because git does not see a local file `page/Advanced Types.md`. Yes or not?

Comment: You missed an `s` in `pages` there. Try `git checkout uk -- "pages/Advanced Types.md"`.

Comment: I am very ashamed =). How delete this "question"?

Comment: It happens ;-) Don't worry about it.

Comment: @ktretyak thanks for not deleting the question. It just saved me some time :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a typo - `page` instead of `pages` :-)

Comment: Thank you, @Kenney is immediately noticed this.

Comment: @dotnetdom, this is a prefectly valid answer.