# Does a git branch have a corresponding Linux shell absolute file path?

Tags: bash, git, shell

I have two branches: master and working.  I'm currently on the working branch, but I want to reference a file which only exists in the master branch, without checking out that branch.  Is there some shell syntax which lets me reference that file in branch master?

For example:

```
$ some-tool git:master!some-file.txt
```

Comment: No. But there is a git command to do that. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2364147/13860).

Comment: Is `some-tool` a generic Linux tool that doesn't know anything about git, or are you asking how to do such a reference in git-specific tooling?

Comment: some-tool is a generic Linux tool, perhaps a shell script that I've written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but using [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) you can generate a path that corresponds to a FIFO attached to an arbitrary command's output. Thus, if the "arbitrary command" retrieves your file from git (and your tool can read from a FIFO rather than needing a seekable file), there you are.

```
some-tool <(git show master:some-file.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash, or another shell that supports process substitution, this should work:

```
$ some-tool <(git show <BRANCH>:<PATH_FROM_GITROOT>)
```

`<()` creates a file handle in `/dev/fd` or a named pipe depending on implementation, which contains the content of the subcommand AFAIK.

Comment: Heh. 14 seconds apart. BTW, this is a feature bash borrowed from ksh, so while it's not available in POSIX sh, neither is it bash-only.

Comment: ...btw, while `/dev/fd` is how it works on Linux, when compiled on platforms where the kernel doesn't offer that facility bash will use a named pipe instead.

Comment: Wasn't aware that is isn't bash only, I'm aware that zsh has its own different equivalent so I just assumed it was a bashism. Also wasn't aware you could get a named pipe from this, will update answer.

Comment: Thanks to both @Carey