# How to get a file from stash which has been save in untracked state?

Tags: git

Consider the following workflow: I created new (untracked) tests for a class after making changes to it which made the tests necessary and then realized that I need to change the logic of another set of tests which I thought would be a different commit, so I ran `git stash save -u`. Then, I realized that I need the stashed tests. How to get them as easy as possible?

My approach would be `git stash branch` and checkout the untracked test files (as described in [How to get just one file from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch)), but that only works if no conflicts occur if the stash is applied (warning: `git stash branch` pops the stash anyway and messes up your working directory although failing with a verbose error message would be the way to go here).

I only want the untracked file(s) from the stash, but not the rest of it.

I'm using git 2.14.1 on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: You can apply a stash without removing it from the stash.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That leads me to the clarification in the last sentence, thank you (I'm assuming that `git stash apply` doesn't have a pathspec argument, at least I don't find one in the manpages).

Comment: So have you committed your other tests already? And you can't unstash due to a conflict right?

Comment: @dimwittedanimal Nothing has been committed. The sequence is: changes on untracked and tracked files -> `stash save -u` -> changes on tracked files -> need untracked files from `stash@{0}`

Comment: Honestly I've started committing temporary stuff more than stashing.

Comment: I agree that this has it advantages, however the tradeoff is a messed up `reflog` which is a good aid when working on different feature branches for some time and then come back after a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would solve this, based on comments.

```
git checkout -b <clean branch, before changes>
git stash apply
```

Here, you'll have tracked & untracked files. You can then use:

```
git reset HEAD <tracked files>
git checkout <clean branch> -- <"tracked files">
```

This should reset them to the clean branch state. Then you just need to:

```
git add <untracked files>
git commit -m "Tests"
git checkout <old, dirty branch>
```

Continue making changes, until ready for commit.

```
git commit -m "More Tests"
git merge <clean branch, before changes>
```

There's probably some errors here, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to say. At this point you'll likely have conflicts, that you can deal with however you deal with conflicts.

*Edit:* Of course, depending on how many changes you have, merging and dealing with conflicts may not be the best/fastest way to do this. If it's like one file that's changed, I'd do the same flow, but after removing the tracked files, I would just bring in the changes from the `<old, dirty branch>` into the `<clean branch, with untracked changes, potentially already committed>`.

Comment: Looking good, thank you! I think I know what you mean with it, but the terms "clean" and "dirty" branch could use more clarity. I assume that by the first "clean branch, before changes" you mean a new branch, eventually stashing (or committing on a separate branch and going back) the changes after the first stash.

Comment: Yeah, so `clean branch` is meant to be whatever branch you were working off of, whether that be `development`, `dev`, whatever, up to date with the latest commits before you made your test changes. It's kinda hard because I wasn't given any branch names to utilize.