# How to completely replace one file in GIt

Tags: git

All:

I am pretty new in Git, I wonder how can I replace one file with the one from master?

Foe example:

In branch DEV, I have one file called App.js, I decide to use the App.js from master branch to replace it. What is the command to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get just one file from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on `DEV` branch and you want to overwrite only one file from `master` remote branch:

```
git fetch 
git checkout origin/master <filepath>
```