# Overriding files in master branch due to changes in another branch

Tags: git

Let's say I have a file named index.html in my master branch, I made some changes of the file in another branch name features. How can I replace the index.html file in the master branch by the index.html file in the features branch

I once tried

```
> git checkout master
> git merge features
```

but it seems it copied the content thereby creating redundancies

Comment: You are describing a normal workflow where you merge in a changes, and what you tried is probably the correct approach. Can you elaborate on your last sentence? What do you mean by "copied the content thereby creating redundancies"?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way:

```
git checkout feature -- index.html
git commit -m "index.html from feature branch"
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer, we should update the question to specify only one file is desired from the features branch. But in that case this is probably just a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2364147/184546.