# Pick a single file from a commit in a branch and move it in another branch

Tags: git

I have 2 branches that are children of the `dev` branch, let's say `dev/branchA` and `dev/branchB`. I want to pick a single file from the last commit of `dev/branchA` and overwrite it in `dev/branchB`. The path and the filename are the same. How can i do it only using `git`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get just one file from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `checkout` the file from `branchA`:

```sh
git checkout branchB
git checkout branchA path/to/file
```

Or, since [Git 2.23](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore/2.23.0):

```sh
git restore --source branchB path/to/file
```