# GitLab: Get commit for included .yml file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

.gitlab-ci.yml file includes another .yml file:

```
    include:
      - project: "test_repository"
        ref: "develop"
        file: "template.yml"
```

While pipeline execution 'template.yml' is taken from HEAD of 'develop' branch in 'test_repository'. Is it possible get 'template.yml' commit somehow after or while the pipeline execution?

Comment: You could use curl to query the gitlab api for the commit of the repo.

Comment: As long as `git` is available in the image you use (assuming you're using the Docker executor for your runners), you could always [checkout the file from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2364147/2307873).

Comment: Want to have some universal solution, because have more than 10 repositories with different includes. I thought that it should be some record in a job logs or some system variable with commit, but I did not find it.